# PrimeNG not working with Angular 2

Tags: angular, primeng

I believe I have followed the instructions for integrating PrmeNG but am getting the following error:

Error {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Template parse errors:
'p-rating' is not a known element:
1. If 'p-rating' is an Angular comp……}

I have imported the module in app.module.ts:

```
import {RatingModule} from 'primeng/primeng';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RatingModule
    ]
})
```

In my html, I use it as follows:

```
<p-rating [ngModel]="product.rating" readonly="true" stars="5"></p-rating>
```

But get the error shown above.

Comment: Can you put your code and ngmodule code and the package.json? Or preferably put a plunker?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/VnQzlxMraqXK8HbWxK8o

Comment: Where is PrimeNg in your config.js or package.json or in your index.html? Without which can you expect the object to be there?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have primeNg in your **`package.json`** or **`system.config.js`** to make it work.

```
 map: {
 'primeng':'npm:primeng@2.0.1/primeng.js'
}
```

Read the official **[`documentation`](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup)**

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/jeRBgasaVm0sc5lbZnES?p=preview)**

Comment: I am using angular cli, primeng is already specified in my package.json as per the PrimeNG working example: "primeng": "^4.0.0", Here is a link to the package.json of PrimeNG working example: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng-quickstart-cli/blob/master/package.json. It doesn't seem to contain the configuration you suggested.